# How do I send union to a function

Tags: c++

```
struct drawing {
    int some_variable;
    union time_spent      // How much time was spent on it
    {
        int seconds;
        float minutes;
        float hours;
    };
};

void init(drawing* my_drawing, int some_variable = 1);
```

How do I pass `time_spent` to `void init()` as a parameter of the function? `drawing::time_spent.hours` doesn't work, just plainly says "expected a )". If I use simply `drawing::time_spent`, I can't assign anything to it, it says "No suitable constructor exists".

The program actually shouldn't do anything, I just wanted to show that I understand unions, but I apparently don't understand them at all.

Comment: `init` doesn't take a `time_spent` so you can't pass it one.

Comment: You code looks like C, not C++.

Comment: if you send `drawing` as an argument like you already do, you can access the union with `drawing.time_spent`.

Comment: What is the meaning of the union in this case? And what is the actual attempt? You need to have an instance of the struct to use it somewhere

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. This isnt valid code. Also you just declare a `union` type but you have no instance of it

Comment: @liliscent I read about unions in C++ manual. Are they not supported in C++?

Comment: @TaisiaSharapova: Yes, they are supported

Comment: do you really want to count only `hours` **or** `minutes` **or** `seconds` ? what if it took 1 hour and 59 minutes?

Comment: @user463035818, I would imagine, in this case you would have float hours.

Comment: @Xatyrian I can't, it says either "Expected an identifier" or "Expected a )" if I pass it as a parameter.

Comment: @SergeyA uh yes, I missed the float. Still looks a bit strange to me, but thats offtopic ;)

Comment: @TaisiaSharapova My comment is not about `union`, though it's not very useful for non-pod type. In C++, you have constructor, this `init` function passing by pointer is very C style.

Comment: @user463035818 Yes, as someone said, float hours. What do you mean by "instance" of a union? Should I make a variable before I pass some value to the function?

Comment: I mean that you only have a union type but no value of that type

Comment: @liliscent, oh, I see. I used an example made by our teacher, he made an init with a pointer. Long story short, we just make "prototypes" of some real-world objects via structs and then make empty functions to which we pass struct's parameters. Our teacher used 'enum' in his example but recommended to come up with something of our own. I wanted to use a union but can't pass it as an argument. Passing to init with a pointer is mandatory, however.

Comment: Thats sad. If you are brave you should tell your teacher to stop teaching c++ as if it was c.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin this is supposed to be c++ (unless there is a misunderstanding), which doesnt need the `typedef`

Comment: Well then, there is no need for the hidden `typedef`. I guess that is the problem with mixing the two languages in short snippets.

Answer (score 5):

You can't pass `time_spent` by itself, because `init()` expects a pointer to a `drawing` struct, not a pointer to a `union`, eg:

```
drawing d;
init(&d);
```

Also, your `union` is not declared correctly, anyway.  You are simply declaring a *nested type* named `time_spent`, but you are not declaring any *struct field* using that type.  If you want a struct field named `time_spent`, the `union` should look like this instead:

```
struct drawing {
    int some_variable;
    union
    {
        int seconds;
        float minutes;
        float hours;
    } time_spent; // How much time was spent on it
};
```

That declares a struct field named `time_spent` that is of an anonymous union type.

Alternatively, separate the `union` declaration from the `struct` declaration:

```
union u_time {
    int seconds;
    float minutes;
    float hours;
};

struct drawing {
    int some_variable;
    u_time time_spent; // How much time was spent on it
};
```

Either way, `init()` can then access the `time_spent` field as `my_drawing->time_spent`.

Comment: I can't follow your recommendation in the first four lines. After declaring union and struct I wrote `drawing d;` and `init (&d);`, but it gives me an error: "Incomplete type is not allowed".

Comment: What I have shown is the correct way to use `init()` given the declaration you have shown. If you are having errors, you are doing something wrong. The `drawing` I showed is not an "incomplete type". Even your original `drawing` is not an "incomplete type", either.

Comment: Since I can't copy-paste all my code here, I'm just going to provide a screenshot. [I would be very glad if you explained my mistakes.](https://imgur.com/SqRnmq4) [Here's a version without "void".](https://imgur.com/DlphaDM) Thank you for the attention!

Comment: "*Since I can't copy-paste all my code here*" - you can always edit your question to show your actual code. Especially to provide a [mcve] that allows other people to reproduce the same problem. But, in any case, the error message is complaining about `init()` itself, not what you are passing to `init()`. The error makes me think that the declaration of `init()` is either missing or incorrect

Comment: It heavily changed the problem though. I'll try to figure something out, but if I can't, I'll change the question to this one.